# How to read all ip address from xxx.log file and print their count?

Tags: python-3.x, parsing

I am JasperReports Developer, but my manager moved me to work on Python 3 project to read the IP address from 'fileName.log' file and want me to print the count of IP address if one IP watched my Video more than one time.

I am very new to Python 3. Please help me with this problem.
My file as below:

```
66.23.64.12 - - [06/Nov/2014:19:10:38 +0600] "GET /news/53f8d72920ba2744fe873ebc.html HTTP/1.1" 404 177 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
64.24.65.93 - - [06/Nov/2014:19:11:24 +0600] "GET /?q=%E0%A6%AB%E0%A6%BE%E0%A7%9F%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0 HTTP/1.1" 200 4223 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
78.849.65.62 - - [06/Nov/2014:19:12:14 +0600] "GET /?q=%E0%A6%A6%E0%A7%8B%E0%A7%9F%E0%A6%BE HTTP/1.1" 200 4356 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
78.849.65.62 - - [06/Nov/2014:19:12:14 +0600] "GET /?q=%E0%A6%A6%E0%A7%8B%E0%A7%9F%E0%A6%BE HTTP/1.1" 200 4356 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
98.449.65.19 - - [06/Nov/2014:19:10:38 +0600] "GET /news/53f8d72920ba2744fe873ebc.html HTTP/1.1" 404 177 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
54.49.65.03 - - [06/Nov/2014:19:11:24 +0600] "GET /?q=%E0%A6%AB%E0%A6%BE%E0%A7%9F%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0 HTTP/1.1" 200 4223 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
54.49.65.03 - - [06/Nov/2014:19:11:24 +0600] "GET /?q=%E0%A6%AB%E0%A6%BE%E0%A7%9F%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0 HTTP/1.1" 200 4223 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
45.79.65.62 - - [06/Nov/2014:19:12:14 +0600] "GET /?q=%E0%A6%A6%E0%A7%8B%E0%A7%9F%E0%A6%BE HTTP/1.1" 200 4356 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

Output as below:

```
  IP          Count
98.449.65.19   2
54.49.65.03    4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method, it involves storing the IP address in a dictionary, which may be useful depending on what else you would like to do with the data.

```
# Read in the text file
with open('fileName.log','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

data = {}
for line in lines:
    # Split the line each time a space appears, and take the first element (the IP address)
    print(line) 
    ipAddr = line.split()[0]
    if ipAddr in data:
        data[ipAddr]+=1
    else:
        data[ipAddr]=1

# Print counts of each IP address
print('   IP    Count')
for key, val in data.items():
    print(key, val)
```

Output:

```
   IP    Count
66.23.64.12 1
64.24.65.93 1
78.849.65.62 2
98.449.65.19 1
54.49.65.03 2
45.79.65.62 1
```

Comment: Do we need to mention full path of file here---> with open('fileName.log','r') as f:  even if the file is in same directory?

Comment: Please give your suggestions to learn Python efficiently. Once again thank you.

Comment: If the log file is run from the working directory then you do not need the full path.

Comment: Hi Robbie, I am able to get the count of IP address form log file. For that, thanks a lot Robbie once again. But they are asking count of ACTIVE unique users during a specific time period.

Comment: No problem. That is outside the scope of this question: you haven't defined ACTIVE. I would recommend posting another question (make sure it is specific!) :-)